# how to use the array in Intent?

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-listview

i am creating a simple android app using list activity,  array and intent .
i want to when the user select an item that the system display in a text view the selected item in the second activity using the intent .

but the problem is that the system force close  and display in the log cat the error:

```
12-01 20:58:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(2491): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 20:58:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(2491):     at com.devleb.listviewdemo.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:19)
```

can anyone help me with this problem ???

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.listviewdemo;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    TextView txt;
    private static final String[] items = { "doctor", "engineer", "lawer",
            "developer", "employee", "business man", "auditer", "cashier" };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        // txt.setText(items[position]);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("testonArray", items);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## SecondActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.listviewdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("testonArray");
            txt.setText(value);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is line 19 of SecondActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `txt` reference is `null` since you didn't use `findViewById()` to get a valid reference.

```
txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.yourTextViewId);
txt.setText(value);
```

should work, provided the TextView is in the layout used by `SecondActivity` and it has a valid id.

I also find this line odd

```
String value = extras.getString("testonArray");
```

because in `MainActivity` you put a String array in the Intent, not a just single String.

I would change it to

```
String [] values = extras.getStringArray ("testonArray");
txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.yourTextViewId);
if (values != null && values.length > 0 && txt != null){
   txt.setText(values [0]);
}
```